# Adding either DISTINCT or GROUP BY to my mysql_query is causing no values to be returned

Tags: php, mysql, distinct

I am using php to get records from a mysql database using the following code:

```
<?php
    $username="";
        $password="";
        $database="";
        $hostname="";

               $con = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password);

        if (!$con){
            die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
        }

        mysql_select_db($database, $con);


    if(isset($_POST['emp'])){
        $emp = $_POST['emp'];
        $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM contact_log", $con);
        echo mysql_num_rows($result);
        die();
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
            $emp = $row['emp'];
            echo $emp.'<br>';
        }
        die();
    }

        mysql_close($con);
?>
```

This works fine and returns the correct fields. The problem is that if I change the query to

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT * FROM contact_log", $con);
```

or

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM contact_log GROUP BY emp", $con);
```

no results are returned.

mysql_num_rows does not even return a value which indicates to me that those lines are breaking my code but I am unable to figure out how.

Comment: Since we don't have the schema of your table (you should post it), what do you get if you issue the query on the server using your favorite client?

Comment: If `mysql_num_rows` is failing, it means you got an error in `mysql_query`. Why aren't you checking for errors there? What does `mysql_error()` return?

Comment: BTW, here's the obligatory "Don't use mysql_XXX" functions, you should use mysqli or PDO."

Comment: The schema is emp,date,title and without adding distinct or order by I get get a list of all emp

Answer (score 0):

I doubt you want to do a `distinct *` on your first query.  Looking at your code, you probably want:

```
"SELECT DISTINCT emp FROM contact_log"
```

And you can get more information about what is going wrong with `mysql_error`:

```
mysql_query("select * from table") or die(mysql_error())
```

Finally, are you sure that `$_POST['emp']` is being sent?  Put an echo right after that if to make sure.  And just so you know, you aren't using the `emp` POST variable for anything other than a flag to enter that block of code.  `$emp = $_POST['emp'];` is doing absolutely nothing.

Comment: "SELECT DISTINCT emp FROM contact_log" produces the same result.

Using your method I was able to determine:

Can't create/write to file 'C:\Windows\SERVIC~2\NETWOR~1\AppData\Local\Temp\#sql44c_1d2a_0.MYI' (Errcode: 13)

Comment: I don't know why you'd have to write to that file to do a simple select.  Can you do that same query in phpmyadmin or another mysql client?

Comment: I get the same error in phpmyadmin. I never set that directory so it must be a default somewhere. Is there somewhere I can change that?

Comment: I have no clue, but we've learned that your php and mysql syntax is completely fine, you have an issue with your system.  if you are on a paid hosting plan, i'd email in customer support with that error message. I've never seen anything like that before.